# Change a Paid Android app to a subscription app in Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, subscription

It is a one time payment app. Now I wish to change it and make app from Paid (one time) to subscription (yearly payment).

It should be affect to new users only. Existing users will keep app as it is, and new users will have to pay it every year. Can I under this app make option to pay one time (for 20$) or pay yearly (for 5$) and let new users to choose?

Can it be done like this:
**There is "unpublish" opstion in Play console, I can do that, and only old users will have access for reinstall/update. I did not find is there option to upload new app (same as old unpublished) and offer it with subscription payment.
Best way would be to have one, updated version of this app, where users can choose payment plan, one time payment or yearly.**